# Pandas. Group by index and apply max for column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group dataframe by 3 elements and want to get rows with the highest column value from the group, but `max` method applies to all columns. How can I achieve this?

What I do:

```
In [69]: fr
Out[69]:
             ping  delta
0   1516190798773    161
1   1516191845372    143
2   1516192904988    144

3   1516193952748    295
4   1516195008033    233
5   1516196049407    252

In [70]: fr.groupby(fr.index / 3).max()
Out[70]:
            ping  delta
0  1516192904988    161
1  1516196049407    295
```

Result I want to get:

```
            ping  delta
0  1516190798773    161
1  1516193952748    295
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If want `first` value in `ping` column and `max` value in `delta`:

```
df = fr.groupby(fr.index // 3).agg({'delta':'max','ping':'first'})
print (df)
            ping  delta
0  1516190798773    161
1  1516193952748    295
```

If want `max` value in `delta` and all coresponding rows:

```
df = fr.loc[fr.groupby(fr.index // 3)['delta'].idxmax()]
print (df)
            ping  delta
0  1516190798773    161
3  1516193952748    295
```

Better sample for difference:

```
print (fr)
            ping  delta
0  1516190798773    161
1  1516191845372    143
2  1516192904988    144
3  1516193952748    233 <-swapped values 233
4  1516195008033    295 <-swapped values 295
5  1516196049407    252

df = fr.groupby(fr.index // 3).agg({'delta':'max','ping':'first'})
print (df)
            ping  delta
0  1516190798773    161
1  1516193952748    295

df = fr.loc[fr.groupby(fr.index // 3)['delta'].idxmax()]
print (df)
            ping  delta
0  1516190798773    161
4  1516195008033    295
```